# Can somebody tell steps to use OpenAMQ C lib to connect to rabbitMQ server

Tags: c, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to use RabbitMQ in my C/C++ app, so far I have realized that using OpenAMQ's C Client is the only option, but OpenAMQ is AMQP 0-9 something and RabbitMQ server is 0-8. I have read somewhere that people were successful to do minor changes to RabbitMQ to make it work with OpenAMQ C lib.. can somebody experienced with this throw some light.

Answer (score 1):

With [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) use *RabbitMQ C AMQP client library* available at https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.